# Binding Controls to DataGrid in Visual Studio generates Object Reference Error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, compiler-errors

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I am using the procedure described here: [MS Instructions for Visual Implementation of bound controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264923%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I find the data view in Data Sources that I want.  I check that I want a DataGrid control.  I drag the source to the Designer window and place my grid into a StackPanel.

Everything looks good.  EXCEPT

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Load data into the table dbQueueTable. You can modify this code as needed.
    TradeX_wpf.tradexDataSetTableAdapters.dbQueueTableAdapter tradexDataSetdbQueueTableAdapter = new TradeX_wpf.tradexDataSetTableAdapters.dbQueueTableAdapter();
    tradexDataSetdbQueueTableAdapter.Fill(tradexDataSet.dbQueueTable);
    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource dbQueueTableViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("dbQueueTableViewSource")));
    dbQueueTableViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
}
```

The ...Fill(tradexDataSet.dbQueueTable) generates an error saying

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TradeX_wpf.tradexDataSet.dbQueueTable.get'

What does this mean?  What is missing in the documentation that I have not done?  What do I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicated, you need to create instance of `tradexDataSet` and pass it to the method instead of passing the class name it self. Try to replace this line :

```
tradexDataSetdbQueueTableAdapter.Fill(tradexDataSet.dbQueueTable);
```

with this :

```
myTradexDataSet = new tradexDataSet();
tradexDataSetdbQueueTableAdapter.Fill(myTradexDataSet.dbQueueTable);
```

Comment: That eliminates the error, but the datagrid is still not loading data AND I would still like to know why the automatic code generation is wrong.  I wonder if the failure to load the datagrid is because some other auto generated code is wrong too -- though not causing a compiler error.  Thanks.

Comment: Your current question is clear, error message and relevant code provided, so I can give solution. About why datagrid still can't load the data, we can't give any suggestion, since we know nothing about exact step you did, how your current code look like, and other relevant information. The link you refer is hard to follow, so I can't guess what you did by looking at the article. Also that should be posted as new question (provide relevant information/codes there). One question for one specific problem.

Comment: I created a new application an bound the tables successfully, so you are correct, there is something else in the original code messing me up.  Thanks for the info.